# how do i create a method that will get data from sqlite database and display it in a fragment using that method

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

This is a fragment.I would like to get a specific data from the database and store it in a string then put it in a textview but i dont know how to construct the method and also how to use that method to get the data.(cursor)
please help me guys..

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lyrics,
    container, false);
    int hymnNo = fragVal - 1;
        //Database
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
    String lyrics = myDbHelper.data(hymnNo);


    View tv = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    //((TextView) tv).setText("Hymn Nunmber " + hymnNo);
    return layoutView;
    }
```

Here is the database helper class DataBaseHelper.java

```
public Cursor data(int x){
    SQLiteDatabase db =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH,null,
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select Lyrics from Hymns where id = " + x , null);
    db.close();
return c;
}
```

Comment: refer to http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Try, create this method on your DataBaseHelper.java class

```
public String getData(int x) {
    String dataReturn = null;

    SQLiteDatabase db =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH,null,
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select Lyrics from Hymns where id = " + x , null);

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            dataReturn = cursor.getString(0);
            /** 0 is column position in database that you want to retrieve, it depend on your database settings */
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        idReturn = "empty";
    } finally {
        db.close();
        return dataReturn ;
    }
}
```

Set TextView text using following code:

```
View tv = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText(myDbHelper.getData(hymnNo));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from Database Create Method like below :

```
public String getDataFromDatabase(int id) {
    String dataReturn = null;

    SQLiteDatabase db =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH,null,
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select Lyrics from Hymns where id = " + x , null);
    if(c!= null){
    try {
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             dataReturn = cursor.getString(1);
         }
     }  catch (Exception ex) {
         idReturn = "empty";
     }  finally {
         db.close();
         return dataReturn ;
     }
  }
  return dataReturn ;
}
```

And then set it in your textview as below :

```
tv.setText(DATABASECLASS.getDataFromDatabase(ID));
```